# OnValueChanged требует указать значение?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда я создал один слайдер то всё нормально:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда создал второй, то OnValueChanged требует указать передаваемое значение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public void SensorUpdate(float value)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Sensitivity", value);
        sliderSensitivity.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Sensitivity");
        sensitivity.text = Mathf.RoundToInt(value * 100) + "%";
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }


    public void FOVUpdate(float value)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FOV", Convert.ToInt32(value));
        sliderFOV.value = Convert.ToSingle(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FOV"));
        FOV.text = Convert.ToInt32(value).ToString();
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
```

вот код но я сомневаюсь что это поможет

Comment: Вместо того чтобы ставить минусы вопросу, лучше объясните что я сделал не так или скажите чем дополнить вопрос.

Comment: вопрос неконкретный. Неясно что такое нормально а что такое ненормально в твоем понимании. Оракулы читающие твои мысли и твое виденье мира в отпуске, прийдется писать словами. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . (Минус не мой если что)

Comment: Посмотрите в чем разница между методами `SensorUpdate` и `FOVUpdate` . Особенно обратите внимание на то какие параметры принимают эти методы :)

Comment: они принимают значения одинакового типа

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Разобрался сам, вобщем нужно как на картинке сделать, т.е. не из Static Parametrs, а Dynamic float.